# How do I combine COUNTIF with OR

Tags: regex, google-sheets, countif, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

In Google Spreadsheets, I need to use the `COUNTIF` function on a range with multiple criteria.  So in the table below, I would need to have something like `=COUNTIF(B:B,"Mammal"or"Bird")` and return a value of 4.

```
A         |B
-------------------
Animal    | Type
-------------------
Dog       | Mammal
Cat       | Mammal
Lizard    | Reptile
Snake     | Reptile
Alligator | Reptile
Dove      | Bird
Chicken   | Bird
```

I've tried a lot of different approaches with no luck.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

One option:

```
=COUNTIF(B:B; "Mammal") + COUNTIF(B:B; "Bird")
```

According to the documentation:

> **Notes**
>
> [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093480) can only perform conditional counts with a single criterion.
>   To use multiple criteria, use [COUNTIFS](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3256550) or the database functions
>   [DCOUNT](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3094222) or [DCOUNTA](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3094147).

[`COUNTIFS`](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3256550): This function is only available in the [new Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3541068).

Example:

```
=DCOUNTA(B:B; 2; {"Type"; "Mammal"; "Bird"})
```

Comment: Thanks wchiquito - DCOUNTA works perfectly.  I am curious what the "2" in that formula does exactly.  The formula seems to work as expected regardless of what that number is, so long as it's equal to or greater than 1.

Comment: @VivaNOLA: Index indicating which column to consider. See [DCOUNTA](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3094147)

Comment: *NB:* watch out for cases when there are rows matching _both_ criteria; those will be counted twice.

Answer (score 14):

You can also use ArrayFormula around a SUM(COUNTIFS()) construct:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(COUNTIF(B:B,{"Mammal", "Bird"}))
```

---

[Source: Google Docs Product Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/docs/safari/dYaR9s1yV-s)

Comment: ArrayFormula is much better and certainly more maintainable that typing ranges and strings over and over again with COUNTIFS.  Thank-you for finding this!!!

Answer (score 4):

you can use regex like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(N(REGEXMATCH(B:B, "Mammal|Bird"))))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `QUERY` which can be very powerful (and is generally easier to remember, particularly if you came from the DB world) :

```
QUERY(A:B;"SELECT COUNT(B) WHERE B='Mammal' OR B='Bird'";0)
```

*(`0` at the end is used to avoid including header rows if you have such in your range)*

Documentation about the `QUERY` function here : https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en